# Solving linear system $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, approximation, fixed-point-theorems

To solve Ax=b by using an approximation that gives an approximate solution $x^*$ satisfying $Ax^*=b+b^*$. If we know $\frac {||b^*||} {||b||} \le 10^{-3}$, what can we say about $\frac {||x^*-x||} {||x||}$?

I guess I can do $(Ax-Ax^*)/Ax=(b+b^*-b)/b$ which yields $A(x-x^*)/Ax=(b^*)/b$? how do i go from here? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The terms you are looking for are forward error and backward error, as introduced in this [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability).

You are searching the backwards error when given a apecific forward error. 
In many cases, this can be done by the condition number ot $A$.

Comment: so what i am doing is totally off? can you please briefly explain how i can apply backward error in this problem? or give a hint

Comment: You are dividing vectors, which is an invalid operation. In addition, the concept is well known in numerics, so just read about the concition number of matrices

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read a book on numerical linear algebra.  The answer you seek is, for example, in https://s3.amazonaws.com/ulaff/LAFF-NLA.pdf (Chapter 2).  But you can also find it in excellent books by Watkins, or Golub and Van Loan.

Comment: Additional comment: as pointed out by others, this is a classic problem of numerical analysis.  The idea is that if you try to solve $ A x = b $ in the presence of roundoff error, you get an approximate solution that satisfies $ A \widetilde x = \widetilde b $.   The question then is by how much the relative error in $ b $, given by $\| \widetilde b - b \| / \| b \| $ is may be amplified into a relative error in $ x $, given by $\| \widetilde x- x \| / \| x \| $.  Here $ \| \cdot \| $ is a norm.